# Exposing Docker port to Local Network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've created a docker container with server hosting a website. I want to access that website in my LAN network (i.e. everyone having access to my router should be able to do it).

This is part of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
synceddb:
      image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}synceddb
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: SyncedDB/Dockerfile
      depends_on:
        - mongo
      environment:
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
        - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44361
      ports:
        - "10002:80"
        - "44361:443"
      volumes:
        - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
        - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

When I run this container, I'm able to open my website calling `https://localhost:44361` in my web browser (on host machine).

To enable other devices to access it, I've created Inbound Rule in Windows Firewall. I've allowed TCP protocol type for port 44361. It doesn't work, typing IP adress of my computer with port 44361 doesn't return anything. Even disabling Firewall doesn't solve the problem. Do I miss something?

I'm using Docker for Windows.

Comment: Before hitting `https://localhost:44361` fro your browser, have you tried this `https://ip:44361` where ip is your machine ip. Hit this from your machine and check the behaviour first if it didn't worked then you have to specify your machine ip (or 0.0.0.0) in the application config somewhere.

Comment: you have to set port forwarding in your router config.